# Clases css anidadas en Material UI

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, pseudoelementos

lo que he estado tratando de hacer es algo similar a lo que se suele hacer en css de que tu puedes anidar las clases para ir como que adentrandote en las clases y cambiando el estilo dependiendo de las ubicaciones de tus clases, por ejemplo en css se hace

```
.myClass{
    color: red;
    .myOtherClass{
        color: blue;
    }
}
```

Entonces los que no contengan a `myOtherClass` pero si se encuentren dentro de `myClass` tendran la letra roja. Los que se encuentren dentro de `myClass` y tengan `myOtherClass` tendran la letra azul. Esto lo quisiera replicar en MaterialUI pero no logro hacerlo

```
  leader: {
    position: "absolute",
    color: "#FFF",
    fontSize: "0.8em",
    "&:nth-child(1)": {//Este pseudoelemento si me funciona, se posiciona donde quiero
      right: "25%",
      top: "75%",
      "p &:nth-child(1)": {//Este pseudoelemento no jala y se que existe.
        //Aqui es donde quisiera modificar cada etiqueta hija de leader
        color: "red"
      },
    },
```

También he intentado usar como

- "LeaderName"
- .LeaderName
- LeaderName
- "LeaderName &:nth-child(1)"

El HTML está compuesto de la siguiente forma:

```
<div className={leader}>
      <div className={Hexagon}></div>
      <Typography align="center" className={LeaderName}> <!-- Este es el del ejemplo -->
        Pedro
      </Typography>
          <Typography align="center" className={LeaderPosition}>
            CEO
          </Typography>
      <Typography align="center">
            GT
      </Typography>

</div>
```

Cabe mencionar que `Typography` el navegador lo reconoce como una etiqueta `p`

Comment: En sass el & se utiliza para "pegar" tu línea a la anterior clase (clase padre en la que te encuentras en ese momento, es un poco como el `this` en programación vaya). Entonces la línea `"p &:nth-child(1)"` debería ser `"p:nth-child(1)"`, puesto que no hay ningún otro anidamiento.

Comment: @Benito-B Gracias por el dato del `&` pero no funciona, sigue sin hacer caso, no aparece en el inspeccionador de código